# How to move manipulator to an upward pose with Descartes?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [Getting Started with Descartes](http://wiki.ros.org/descartes/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20Descartes), it assumes the end effector is at upward direction. However, my manipulator is initialized with a horizontal pose, like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3vX0XuPbjpRRGw2UGt1M0ZfdXM/view?usp=sharing).

How to move the end effector to upward direction with Descartes API?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227431/how-to-move-manipulator-to-an-upward-pose-with-descartes?/) by [Yishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26015/yishin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a solution here:
[How to specify trajectory points with 6D pose?](https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/descartes/issues/134)

The method is to specify a {X, Y, Z} position with Orientation vector.
Here's the code snippet:

```
using namespace Eigen;
Matrix3d m;
m =   AngleAxisd(0, Vector3d::UnitX())
    * AngleAxisd(-M_PI/2, Vector3d::UnitY())
    * AngleAxisd(0, Vector3d::UnitZ());
pose.linear() = m;
```

---

Originally posted by [Yishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26015/yishin/) with karma: 41 on 2016-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jmeyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26069/jmeyer/) on 2016-02-25**:
I'm glad you found an answer to the issue you were having. If you have more trouble or questions going forward, please feel free to post here or on the Descartes issues page.